# DigestAuthenticationFilter with database users, possible?

Tags: spring, spring-security, http-digest

My Spring-Security implementation for http-digest:
Code:

```
<bean id="digestFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.DigestAuthenticationFilter">
      <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService"/>
      <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="digestEntryPoint"/>
    </bean>

========================================================================

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <security:authentication-provider ref="inMemoryAuthenticationProvider"/>
   </security:authentication-manager>

========================================================================


<bean id="inMemoryAuthenticationProvider"
         class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
      <property name="hideUserNotFoundExceptions" value="false"/>
     <property name="userDetailsService" ref="inMemoryUserService"/> 
      <property name="messageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
   </bean>

========================================================================


<security:user-service id="inMemoryUserService">
        <security:user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>                
        <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:user name="invitado" password="invitado" authorities="ROLE_INVITADO"/>
    </security:user-service>
```

I'm trying to customize it to obtain user data from a database. I tried to access from the Interface class UserDetailsService.
Code:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String arg0)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        return new User(
                "pepe", 
                "psw",
                true,
                true,
                true,
                true,
                authorities);
    }

}
```

This does not work because the label when implementing security: user-service, no class attributes.

Any ideas?, How to access a database of users?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Have you created bean of your `CustomUserDetailsService`?

Comment: Hello, this is the xml configuration works, but users are hadcoding. Users need to access a bbdd, my idea for this access is the class CustomUserDetailsService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<user-service>` tag is used to define users explicitly in the spring configuration file.  It does not allow to specify your own `UserDetailsService` implementation.

To use your `CustomUserDetailsService`, all you have to do is to remove the `<user-service>` tag and replace it by your custom `UserDetailsService` like this :

```
<bean id="inMemoryUserService" class="you.package.CustomUserDetailsService"/>
```

And then you should be able to log in with pepe:psw .